# Configure SonarQube 5.4 to do login via Google account

Tags: authentication, sonarqube, openid, account, sonarqube-web

Is there a way to configure SonarQube v5.4 login via Google Account?

I tried the solution below, but without success.
https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-openid

Answer (score 1):

You can use this contribution from an user : https://github.com/steven-turner/sonar-auth-google

Answer (score 0):

I've used this plugin and it works ok with SonarQube 5.4.

https://github.com/zeroturnaround/sonar-auth-google